# Highlighting weekend days (sat and sun) in Material UI date picker

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

I have requirement wherein I want my date picker to highlight weekend days i.e saturday and sunday. I have been using [material-Ui-datepicker](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/datepicker). I tried various way but not working. Please anyone can help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `renderDay` prop. It allows customizing any day.

Here is an official example of how to change displaying of random day. You basically need to change the appearance for weekends. https://material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/datepicker#customization

Example of function for v3

```js
renderDay={(day, selected, dayComponent) => { 
  if (isWeekend(day)) {
    return React.cloneElemnt(dayComponent, { className: 'your-css' })
  } 

  return dayComponent
}
```

Example of function for v4

```js
renderDay={(day, selected, DayProps) => { 
  if (isWeekend(day)) {
    return <Day {...DayProps} className={clsx(DayProps.classname, 'your-css')} /> 
  } 

  return <Day {...DayProps} />
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was trying to use that but it highlights full week and i need weekends of month. There is a function eachweekendofmonth, it returns weekends, but how do i use it i cannot understand. How it will target sat and sun of month in datepicker

Comment: Add an example to the answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
import {isSaturday} from "date-fns";

const CustomDay = (props) => {
    const isSaturdayHighlighted = isSaturday(props.day);
    const matchedStyles = isSaturdayHighlighted
        ? { backgroundColor: "#ffe8e8", color: "#ff0000" } // Add your custom styles for highlighting Saturdays
        : {};
    return <PickersDay {...props} sx={{ ...matchedStyles }} />;
};

<DatePicker
slots={{ day: CustomDay }}
/>
```

Comment: wrap the datepicker by using <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>

Comment: You should provide some explanation for your code. Also you should edit your answer instead of adding mode code in comments.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).