# Highlighting days in a Material UI StaticDateRangePicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a Material UI `v4.0.0-alpha.12` [StaticDateRangePicker](https://v4-0-0-alpha-12.material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/daterangepicker#static-mode):

[image]

I want to change the color of all Sundays to red. I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61522993/7655409) to use a `renderDay` prop. The changing of the color is working fine but now the blue highlighting of the days within the range is broken:

[image]

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

[Sample on CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/old-river-cguy4). (There another bug occurs which I do not have in my actual code: the red highlighting of the Sundays works only after making a change to the source code.)

**Edit:** Actually not only the Sundays should be red but also Saturdays and (German) public holidays.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by forgetting renderDay and using CSS only:

```
.MuiPickersCalendar-week
  .MuiPickersDateRangeDay-root:nth-child(1)
  .MuiPickersDay-dayLabel {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Okay, then I did simplify too much my problem in the question. Actually not only the Sundays should be red but also Saturdays and (German) public holidays. Then your CSS solution won't work?